# MS Exchange 2010 some mails missing senders name

Tags: exchange, outlook

One of our Users has the problem that some of his mails have missing sender names. It is not a problem of our addressbook or the users contacts, because in the emails preview pane the senders name is visible.

The name is missing in outlook and owa. We have a Exchange 2010 and the user tried Outlook 2010 and 2016. In both of them the same Problem.

[Here is a Screenshot (OWA)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JtzG.png)

Does anyone know that Problem or has a solution?

Comment: Which Exchange 2010 Version are you running? It looks more if that is an issue with MS Exchange (as its also not working in OWA). Can you post the email header here and remove any sensitive information?

Comment: @BastianW The Exchange 2010 Version is 14.03.0319.002 and here is a screenshot of the email header of one of this mails: http://imgur.com/0MiKr9U

Comment: That is CU 15(13-09-2016) you have multiple  security vulnerabilities unclosed which are solved in CU 18. It might also that a more up to date version will solve your issue. So i would really check that before you do anything else.

Comment: @BastianW I just updated the Exchange to CU18 but the problem still remains. Any other ideas?

Comment: How are the emails coming into the environment? Could you naildown those emails to a special company/server? Is that happening always with the same user or are some emails from that user fine? Are the emails S/Mime signed/encrypted? Do you use any Exchange plugins (antispam or antivirus, if yes which one)? Is that happening with replys or only with new emails? Can you reproduce that somehow (e.g. via [telnet](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/exchange/352-howto-send-an-email-using-telnet.html))?